# iPhone SDK 4.0: Testing if view is displayed

Tags: iphone

using iPhone SDK 4.0, how does one determine if a UIViewController is currently in the viewDidAppear state (currently visible). I could set a flag but was wondering if there is a better way.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to know this information? I'm asking because there probably is a better way to do what you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, setting a flag is the best way, as you never know if something is in front of it.

---

Have fun!